Disjointed invervals for a Poisson process
Let $\{N(t); t>0\}$ be a Poisson Process with intensity $\lambda$ > $0$, and I should compute $E(N(2)(N(4)-N(1)))$. This can be written as
$E\Big(\big(N(2)-N(1)+N(1)\big)\big(N(4)-N(2)+N(2)-N(1)\big)\Big)$,
which can be expanded to
$E((N(2)−N(1))(N(4)−N(2)))+E((N(2)−N(1))^2)+E(N(1)(N(4)−N(1)))$.
I don't understand how I end up with that expansion; why is $(N(2)−N(1))$ muliplied by $(N(4)−N(2))$, etcetera?

To exploit the property of independent increments that the Poisson process possesses.

@Mr.Gandalf Sauron, that is not an answer to my question.

$$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+b(c+d)$$
where

$a=N(2)-N(1)$
$b=N(1)$
$c=N(4)-N(2)$
$d=N(2)-N(1)$

